# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string. c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, viewstate

I've been encountering this error message for a while. I tried to replicate the issue and was successful on replicating it by clicking on a wizard button while the loading is still on going. I tried to disable the buttons and other elements by using a script that will disable this elements during pageload and will enable them after  but it still not works. I supposed this issue is because of postback but the fix is not working. And I am not sure if that is the only way to replicate the issue but so far thats the only way i found it.

Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

> System.FormatException Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or
>   string. 
>  System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The client
>   disconnected.  
> ---> System.Web.UI.ViewStateException: Invalid
>   viewstate. 
>  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64
>   11316.123.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.97 Safari/537.36
>
> ViewState:
>   vwfnk+yfSQJi22s3A+upcornE4ngrVGbj7MGaXOxHO1mBsxv/1m0vyMIlLBc3FhiXWqXouB/DlFlt/E9QOF26fNkngtxeJ53g2gSdz4BhaDcFamwFAhwqu32CDkFUW84/+cpdJpvgEz7gZ3EIEmX4xo8gZLXMDcNV4g1cd9ELHmlyUZAw7W4denfEcZmLkGoA1FyGuGb9O0uJILVddcvB4ZZDmciIxzyLr8nczysqqOi9Ml
>   
> ---> System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char
>   array or string. 
>  
>  at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char*
>   startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32
>   destLength) 
>  at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr,
>   Int32 inputLength) 
>  at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
>   at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String
>   inputString, Purpose purpose) 
>   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter,
>   String serializedState, Purpose purpose) 
>  at
>   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() 
>    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: note that i got  validationkey in the webconfig.

Comment: does chunking the viewstate will solve this issue? Im hesitant on touching the web.config, and chunking the viewstate might cause a different error.